# My fragment is showing under WrongTab using ActionBar in Android?

Tags: android

Hi i am using ActionBar by targeting ICS and above.

I am displaying 3 Tabs, in this each tab associated with one fragment.

i.e  TAB1                TAB2          TAB3

```
 fragment1          fragment2     fragment3
```

In my application flow, for some how reason am replacing fragment1 with fragment3 under TAB1. In this case fragment3 will be showing under TAB1, this will become wrong flow in the user perspective. fragment3 should be shown under TAB3. When ever i will replace the fragment i want to change the corresponding tab selection.
Can any one help me out on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take following approach.

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS); // I assume you are using this
```

> When ever i will replace the fragment i want to change the
>   corresponding tab selection

Whenever you are chaning Fragment1 to Fragment3 you should take care to switch tabs too

```
getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(index of tab 3);
```

Comment: Thank for your replay vipul, But i am using exactly what ever you are suggested. actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS); and getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(index of tab 3); This is working fine, but after that if i try to click on Tab3 my app crashing and while going through the logs it saying that the tab already selected.